# How to execute a VBScript file by clicking a button in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, vbscript, firefox-addon, xul

I google my last important hours in searching a command in XUL/Javascript by which I can run a VBScript file by clicking on a button/image inside browser. Is there any way to do this task ( only for Firefox) ?

Comment: you have run it by wscript because firefox doesn't support vbscript!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBScript can only be run in IE browsers. Although Wikipedia articles aren't my first choice, you can read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript